# Create a new column that is the sum of the number of dates in multiple other columns that satisfy two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this (except the number of `Visit` and `Deliv` columns goes up to `Visit_84` and `Deliv 84` and there are several hundred clients - I have simplified it here)

```
Client   Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Deliv_1  Deliv_2  Deliv_3 Key_DT
Client_1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-02-10 No       Yes      Yes     2018-01-15
Client_2 2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 Yes      Yes      No      2018-01-25
Client_3 2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 Yes      Yes      Yes     2018-04-15
Client_4 2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 Yes      No       Yes     2018-02-25
```

I want to create a new column called `Vis_sum` that shows the sum of the number of visits from `Visit_1` to `Visit_3` that come after the `Key_DT` in the same row and have a `Yes` in the associated `Deliv` column (e.g. `Deliv_1` is associated with `Visit_1`). It should look like this

```
Client   Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Deliv_1  Deliv_2  Deliv_3 Key_DT     Vis_sum
Client_1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-02-10 No       Yes      Yes     2018-01-15 2
Client_2 2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 Yes      Yes      No      2018-01-25 1
Client_3 2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 Yes      Yes      Yes     2018-04-15 0
Client_4 2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 Yes      No       Yes     2018-02-25 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This assumes all of your columns are `datetime`. If they are not, convert them.

---

***Setup***

```
a = df.filter(like='Visit').values
b = df.filter(like='Deliv').eq('Yes').values
c = df['Key_DT'].values
```

Using comparison with broadcasting

```
((a > c[:, None]) & b).sum(1)
```

```
array([2, 1, 0, 1])
```

---

```
df.assign(Vis_sum=((a > c[:, None]) & b).sum(1))
```

```
     Client    Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3 Deliv_1 Deliv_2 Deliv_3     Key_DT  Vis_sum
0  Client_1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-02-10      No     Yes     Yes 2018-01-15        2
1  Client_2 2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10     Yes     Yes      No 2018-01-25        1
2  Client_3 2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10     Yes     Yes     Yes 2018-04-15        0
3  Client_4 2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10     Yes      No     Yes 2018-02-25        1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have amended it slightly, as I also need to only carry out the task on clients where the key date is over a certain date. It now looks like this: `df.loc[(df.Key_DT > '2018-02-01'), 'Vis_sum']=((a > c[:, None]) & b).sum(1))`. However, neither this revised code or the original you provided will work. i get the following error message: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1537,81) (1537,12)`. Is the issue that the `Visit` columns, `Deliv` columns and `Key_DT` column all have some missing data in? If so, how do i get around that?

Comment: @FGreen you need to apply the same mask when you create `a`, `b`, and `c` that you do when you index the DataFrame.  So for `a`, it would become `df.filter(like='Visit').loc[df.Key_DT > '2018-02-01']`, etc..

Comment: Thanks. So I've made the following changes:

`a = df.filter(like='Visit').loc[df.Key_DT > '2018-02-01']`
`b = df.filter(like='Deliv').eq('Yes').loc[df.Key_DT > '2018-02-01']`
`c = df['Key_DT'].loc[df.Key_DT > '2018-02-01']`

However, I still get a similar error message: `cannot broadcast shape [(13, 81)] with block values [(13, 1)]`

Comment: Have amended an error (I was using the wrong 'visit' columns) - they error now reads `cannot broadcast shape [(13, 12)] with block values [(13, 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `np` approach:

```
deliv_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Deliv' in col]
visit_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Visit' in col]

flags = df[deliv_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Y'))
date_flags = df[visit_cols].apply(lambda x: x>df.Key_DT)

df['Vis_sum'] = np.sum(flags.values & date_flags.values,axis=1)
```

Comment: As above, I get a similar error message: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1537,12) (1537,81)`

Comment: Check len(deliv_cols) and len(visit_cols). Are they both 84 as claimed?

Comment: Apologies - they are not. there are 84 `visit_cols`, but only 12 `deliv_cols'

Comment: So how do you associate 84 visits with 12 deliveries? I mean it can’t be "visit_1 with deliv_1 and so on" right?

Comment: Ignore that - they are the same length, apologies, 12 visit columns, 12 deliv columns